# Qt ошибка сборки в консольном приложении (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, консоль

Скачал и установил `Qt`, создал проект консольного приложения `Qt` в `Visual Studio`. Написал свой класс с 1 сигналом. Всё запускается нормально, но стоит создать объект класса, то вылетает ошибка:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MyClass1::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MyClass1@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ).
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual void * __cdecl MyClass1::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MyClass1@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z).
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual int __cdecl MyClass1::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MyClass1@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z).
1>C:\Users\Max\source\repos\QtConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\QtConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 3
```

Вот код:

```
#include <QtCore>

class MyClass1 : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass1() : QObject(), inf("Inf from the class MyClass1") {}

    void  sendSignal() {
        emit Test(inf);
    }

private:
    QString inf;

signals:
    void Test(const QString&);

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass1 obj1;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это классическая особенность Qt. Если в cpp файле объявлен класс с макросом `Q_OBJECT`, то вот так и будет.  Лечение - перенести объявление класса в h файл. Либо добавить вот такую строку в файл `#include "main.moc"` (имя совпадает с именем cpp файла, это важно!). И убедится, что moc обрабатывает этот файл. В Qt Creator это обычно автоматом происходит, в студии может быть по другому.

Если используется cmake (ну мало чего), можно посмотреть ещё один мой ответ - [Ошибка “неразрешенный внешний символ..” при наследовании от Q_Object](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162417/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-q-object?rq=1)